# Multiboot not working after Windows 8 / Ubuntu "something else Installation type"

Tags: windows-8, grub2

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 last night on a HDD that already has windows 8 on it by choosing "something else" as an installation type.

- sda1 might be a primary NTFS partition (not sure because Windows 8 installer created it)
- sda2 is a primary NTFS partition (I created it on Ubuntu GParted before I installed Windows 8)
- same goes with sda3 (i.e. as sda2)
- sda5 is swap area partition (I don't recall if I chose logical or primary but GParted says logical)
- sda6 is a logical ext4 partition
- the last line is just free unallocated space

[image]

As I wrote earlier, all partitions were created with a Live CD with Ubuntu's GParted but the sda1 NTFS [Windows 8 (loader)]. And all of the partitions I created I used for "location of the new partition:" the option "beginning of this space".

For the Ubuntu partition I chose `/` as a mounting point. There was a warning saying something like "everything will be deleted on that partition … do you wish to continue?" and I said *yes*.

At the end of the installation there were other warnings. I didn't care to look at them and I clicked OK until the computer restarted. When it did, Windows 8 booted instead of GRUB, meaning that I can't access Ubuntu.

When I boot the computer with Live CD Ubuntu and check gparted I get this:

[image]

**According to gparted sda1 is a primary partition as well**

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Hi Paiku! I've migrated this per your request, but this is just to let you know that Ubuntu questions are perfectly on topic for Super User as well. You can ask them wherever you like, and if you don't get an answer within a day or two, we can always migrate it then.

Comment: What kind of machine are you doing this on? A newer Laptop with UEFI? Read up: http://www.maketecheasier.com/disable-secure-boot-in-windows-8/

Comment: It says its NTFS right in your screenshot.  Please verify the facts of your case.  Makes it hard to help you if you are not even sure of what type of filesystem you were using.  Without the warnings we might not be able to help you.

Comment: No @Ramhound ! What I wasn't sure about was if it was primary or extended logical. I was writing and screenshooting, so when I did the first screenshot I couldn't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are showing standard BIOS/MBR type system. With Windows 8 you still need fast boot off to avoid conflicts.

But you need to install grub2's boot loader into the MBR. All BIOS systems load BIOS, BIOS determines hardware and starts boot from MBR. So boot loader in MBR is still Windows if that is what is booting.

You can install grub2 manually from live installer or use Boot-Repair.
How to restore the Ubuntu/XP/Vista/7 bootloader

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair